# Scraping Multiple Sites for Similar Information

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape several different sites for the same information. Basically, I am looking for similar information, but the sites could belong to different vendors and can have different HTML structures. For example, if I am trying to scrape the data related to text books in Barns&Nobles and Biblio (this is only two but there could be many) and get the book name, author and prices for the books how would one do that?

https://www.barnesandnoble.com/b/textbooks/mathematics/algebra/_/N-8q9Z18k3

https://www.biblio.com/search.php?stage=1&result_type=works&keyisbn=algebra

Of course, I can parse the two sites independently, but I am looking for a general methodology that can be easily applied to other vendors as well to extract the same information.

In a separate but related question, I would also like to know how google show different product information from different sources when you search for a product? For example, if you google for "MacBook Pro", at the top of the page, you'd get a carousel of products from different vendors. I assume google is scraping this information from different sources automatically to suggest to the user what are available.

Comment: There can be no general methodology, to my mind. You should just parse the HTML of these sites and create a data extraction method for each site independently.

Comment: Hey I was thing about, searching a product in google search and parse the search page and find out different url, and then scraping individual url? Just a thought!!! Even I am trying for the same or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: But, you won't be able to make multiple automated search requests to google from a script; it could get blocked

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [scrapely](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely). It can really be helpful if you don't want to manually parse different HTML structures.